# In what order the components in a changeset deployed in a target salesforce org?

Tags: deployment, change-set

When preparing a changeset we usually added components like a custom object, custom fields, pages, trigger, components, etc. I'm wondering if there is any order a changeset would get executed in a target salesforce org?

Thanks,

Comment: There definitely is an order (as per http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/Content/migrate_risks.htm) but I'm not sure the order has ever been published in detail.

Answer (score 3):

I had looked into audit trail CSV file of my deployment to understands the dependencies and by looking at that file the order is as following:

- Pages- i guess first it just deploy empty pages
- Custom Objects - with just fields
- - Track Field History
- - Validation Rules
- Custom fields on Standard object
- Page layouts
- Custom Tabs
- Custom Apps
- Apex Classes
- Apex Trigger
- Manage Users (Profiles)
- Page - i guess this time it deploy the code and overwrite empty page
- search layout

You can use "setup audit trail" option in setup menu to understand your deployment order.

Comment: I guess, Page can't be deployed first (they will have controllers/extension associated with them).

Comment: No it just create empty create empty page first and after controller is deployed then it update the page.